# WordPress categories not showing in list

Tags: wordpress, categories

I'm creating a plugin that adds categories and then lets the user select them in a META box within a custom post.

All my categories are created via my plugin and at all parent categories.

The problem is when I try to provide them in an option group, I don't see them, I only see the original WP "Ucategorized" category.

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong here?

Here is my code:

```
<form id="category-select" class="category-select" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" method="get">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'show_option_none' => __( 'Select a Competency' ),
        'show_count'       => 1,
        'orderby'          => 'name',
        'echo'             => 0,
    );
    ?>
    <?php $select  = wp_dropdown_categories( $args ); ?>
    <?php $replace = "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>"; ?>
    <?php $select  = preg_replace( '#<select([^>]*)>#', $replace, $select ); ?>
    <?php echo $select; ?>
    <noscript>
        <input type="submit" value="View" />
    </noscript>
</form>
```

I've been messing with this for hours and getting nowhere.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `'hide_empty' => false` in your `$args` array. It is skipping over categories with 0 posts.

Comment: Thanks @TheManiac ! That did the trick!  By chance, would you know what would cause an Fatal Error when trying to create child categories? I ask this because I had to create all my categories at the top level due to a Fatal Error using the [ 'parent' => $parent['term_id'], ]. I suppose this is because I'm not able to enter a id #, but not sue.

Comment: @Dennis you should be able to use `wp_insert_term` to accomplish that, and yes, adding a parent ID should work fine. I'm guessing that your `$parent` array isn't what you expect it to be, but I would need more info to make sure. Actually, `$parent` is probably an object, not an array, so you'd need to do `$parent->term_id` -- but again, just a guess.

Comment: Can I open another question, paste my code and somehow invite you to see it?

Comment: Yep, just add the link to the question in the comments here.

Comment: I'll have to wait. I can only post once every 90 mins.

Comment: Hop into chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109117/wordpress-professional-help